# adding coordinates in tikz math does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

If I start with the following MWE,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\tikzmath{
coordinate \A, \B; 
\A =(1,2);
\B =(4,4);
%coordinate \M;
%\M =.5*\A+.5*\B;
}
\draw[fill=black] (\A) circle [radius=1pt] node[above,xshift=-1pt] {$A$};
\draw[fill=black] (\B) circle [radius=1pt] node[above,xshift=-1pt] {$B$};
%\draw[fill=black] (\M) circle [radius=1pt] node[above,xshift=-1pt] {$M$};
\draw (0,4/3)-- (7,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

If I wanted to draw the
midpoint of points A, B, I could add the lines commented out above, namely,

```
coordinate \M;
\M =.5*\A+.5*\B;
```

to get the coordinates of the midpoint. However now I get the following error message:

```
package tikz Error: cannot parse this coordinate
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Why even do it like this? Load the `calc` lib, define `(A)` and `(B)` the normal way, and use `\coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);

Comment: That is true @daleif I just thought I try something else.

Comment: If you load the `calc` library, you can do `\M =.5*(\A)+.5*(\B);` or `\M= (\A)!.5!(\B);`. The coordinate calculation always needs `calc` (both syntaxes are from the `calc` library), `math` doesn't provide this on its own.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes I have used the `calc` library before; I was not aware of the syntax (coordinates have to be in brackets for the algebra to work). Thanks for providing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short description about `pgfmath` package/library we can find in the first three paragraph in

> **Part VIII**
>
> **Mathematical and Object-Oriented Engines**
>
> *by Mark Wibrow and Till Tantau*
>
> PGF comes with two useful engines: One for doing mathematics, one for doing object-oriented programming. Both engines can be used independently of the main PGF.
>
> The job of the mathematical engine is to support mathematical  operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, using both integers and non-integers, but also functions such as square-roots, sine, cosine, and generate pseudo-random numbers. Mostly, you will use the mathematical facilities of PGF indirectly, namely when you write a coordinate like (5cm*3,6cm/4), but the mathematical engine can also be used independently of PGF and TikZ.
>
> The job of the object-oriented engine is to support simple
> object-oriented programming in TEX. It allows the definition of
> classes (without inheritance), methods, attributes and objects.

So package authors are not mentioned, that it can be directly used for determination of coordinates. However, you can use it in calculation of their components, for example value of x-coordinate or y-coordinate, but for calculation with coordinates you need to use different syntax enabled by `calc` library. For example in your case:

```
\tikzmath{
coordinate \A, \B, \M;
\A = (1,2);
\B = (4,4);
\M = ($(\A)!0.5!(\B)$);   % <--- as defined in the `calc`
}
```

See the first example in the MWE below. Using your way for determining of coordinates is unusual and doesn't offer any benefits in comparison to standard way (shown in the second example in MWE below):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}   % used only in the first example

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
              label=#1}
                    ]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\tikzmath{
coordinate \A, \B, \M;
\A = (1,2);
\B = (4,4);
\M = ($(\A)!0.5!(\B)$);
}
\path   (\A) node[dot=$A$] {} -- node (M) [dot=$M$] {} (\B) node[dot=$B$] {};
\draw (0,4/3)-- (7,6);
\node[above right] {with explicit use of the \texttt{tikzmath} library};
\end{tikzpicture}

\qquad or \qquad

\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
              label=#1}
                    ]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);

\path   (A) node[dot=$A$] {} -- node (M) [dot=$M$] {} (B) node[dot=$B$] {};
\draw (0,4/3)-- (7,6);
\node[above right] {without explicit use of the \texttt{tikzmath} library};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm curious, why does `(A) node[dot=$A$] {} -- node (M) [dot=$M$] {} (B) node[dot=$B$] {};` end up placing `M` in the middle. Don't remember seeing that variation before

Comment: @daleif That's the normal [implicit node placement](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9) (which here takes the default `midway`/`pos = 0.5`). The same way every `to`/`edge node` is placed (with or without the `quotes` library). I'd argue this is the default node placement mechanism (along paths at least).

Comment: @daleif, as you see, this works. I use this way to center coordinates, nodes on the path between two coordinates/node for long time. Now I can't remember, where I learn this (in package documentation or in some answer here, on site) .

Comment: @Zarko thanks. My question was directed towards the properties of `coordinate` in `tikzmath`. I just cannot understand why I cannot add coordinates.

Comment: @TedBlack, in my answer your problem is solved on another way, without use of `math` library`. As you can learn from  Qrrbrbirlbel comment, it doesn't  support what you after.